# Using TODAY function with QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I am using this formula (see below) to try and retrieve dates automatically between the current date and the next.  However, I keep getting the error, "*QUERY completed with an empty output.*"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A3:H, HOUR(A3:A)}, 
 "select Col7,sum(Col3),sum(Col5),sum(Col8) 
 where Col1 is not null and Col9=7 
 and Col1 = 'TODAY()' 
 and Col1 = 'TODAY()+1' 
 group by Col7 
 label sum(Col3)'',sum(Col5)'',sum(Col8)''", 0))​​
```

Previously I was using THIS  formula (see below). But with this one, I would have to change the date manually every day.
Not ideal but I was managing.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A3:H, HOUR(A3:A)}, 
 "select Col7,sum(Col3),sum(Col5),sum(Col8) 
 where Col1 is not null and Col9=8 
 and Col1 >= date '2019-08-20' 
 and Col1 <= date '2019-08-21' 
 group by Col7 
label sum(Col3)'',sum(Col5)'',sum(Col8)''", 0))​​
```

Is it possible to use the `TODAY()` function here or should I be looking at other avenues to solve this?

I have included a sample copy of my workbook for anyone to play with. You will find the first formula in `J5` and the second formula in `J27`.

[SAMPLE WORKBOOK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7ZYrd2umuw5K7yBGBwD_jfjcsFAUX3o5uzn8E_rQpU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Related: [Querying for the last results with group by](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/132616/88163)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
date 'TODAY()'
```

use

```
date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"
```

NOTES:

- The last `"` should be placed in a proper place in order to have a text value as the second argument of QUERY.
- `'TODAY()'` doesn't returns Today's date, it returns a string with the word TODAY followed by parenthesis.

Try this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A3:H, HOUR(A3:A)}, 
 "select Col7,sum(Col3),sum(Col5),sum(Col8) 
 where Col1 is not null and Col9=7 
 and Col1 = '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
 and Col1 = '"&TEXT(TODAY() + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
 group by Col7 
 label sum(Col3)'',sum(Col5)'',sum(Col8)''", 0))​​
```

Related

- [Dynamic date range query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74117/88163)
- [QUERY most recent date prior to today](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/94724/88163)
- [Querying for the last results with group by](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/132616/88163)

Answer (score 0):

- paste this in **J5** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY({TO_DATE(INT(A$3:A)), B$3:H, HOUR(A$3:A)},
   "select Col7,sum(Col3),sum(Col5),sum(Col8) 
    where Col1 is not null 
      and Col9 = "&TEXT(INDIRECT("J"&ROW()-1), "h")*1&" 
      and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
      and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    group by Col7", 0), "offset 1", 0)))
  ```

  [image: 0]

---

- then select and copy **J5** and paste in **J27**, **J49**, etc. wherever you need it